# Are the desktop pop-ups feeds working properly?

Tags: support

When I hover over, for example, the Harry Potter tag, and I try and subscribe to the desktop pop-up feed (desktop pop-ups), which I had used for years, and which was an SE feature, and not a third party app, I am now redirected to [a page of RSS code](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/harry-potter). I'm assuming this is not the right selection for pop-ups. Who would I go to, or what can I do, to get the desktop pop-ups working again?

Comment: It looks the same as the info you get when you click the RSS feed for any other tags, [support](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/support), for example.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how RSS works?

Comment: You need some kind of compatible [RSS reader](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-tools-to-display-rss-feed-updates-directly-on-your-windows-desktop/)

Comment: Where are the pop-ups, then?

Comment: Where did you find this link, and what's it meant to do? I can't see it anywhere on the  [HP tag page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter). (Fellow non-programmer here :-D )

Comment: that rss feed looks exactly correct.

Comment: @randal'thor -- It used to be that you could program SFF to send questions of the tags you would choose, so that the question would pop up on your desktop, notifying you there was a new question in the category you signed up for. I have not been able to find it.

Comment: @Slytherincess That sounds like an *excellent* tool! I may well use that when I stop answering *everything* and settle down to concentrate on a few favourite tags like WoT.

Comment: i didnt know there was a native app to do this. looking on meta, everyone just talks about 3rd party apps/scripts.

Comment: @phantom42 -- Yes, I used it for years. When a new question would come in, a pop-up would appear on my desktop with the title of the question and a bit of text. It was a smallpop-up box, about 4" x 4"? It was helpful and I never had to constantly refresh the site to look for new HP questions. I don't know who to ask about this feature. I can't find it anymore. I signed up for questions via email, but that doesn't work well for me because I rarely look at my email. *Sigh*

Comment: @Slytherincess Perhaps it was a feature of your browser? Have you recently switched browsers, or updated?

Comment: If you wait a week or two, one of the SE high-ups may get round to answering this.